# How to create a tentative event using android Calendar Provider

Tags: android, calendar, provider

I'm trying to create a tentative event, which is an exception to recurring events, using android Calendar Provider.

I did succeed in inserting a tentative event into local calendar and it's perfectly

reflected on native google calendar app and other apps as well.

But the problem is it's never synced with the google calendar on the web no matter how much time elapses.

What I do is

A. Create a new event whose originalInstanceTime, original_id, originalAllDay, original_sync_id are set according to the original event.

`cv.put("originalInstanceTime", event.getOriginalInstanceTime());`

`cv.put("original_id", event.getOriginalId());`

`cv.put("originalAllDay", event.getOriginalAllday());`

`cv.put("original_sync_id", event.getSyncId());`

, where event is a simple VO for /events table.

B. insert a tentative event to /events table

`Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/events"), cv);`

That's it. And doing this does make my tentative event show up in other apps (which all share the same embedded calendar) on my android device but the event is never synced with the google web calendar. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.